# Jaxb behaviour is odd

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling, gpx

I am trying to marshall and unmarshal gpx files with an extension. The gpx schema allows to have extension added in the extensions tag example:

```
<trkpt lat="51.219983" lon="6.765224">
    <ele>52.048584</ele>
    <time>2009-06-19T10:13:04Z</time>
    <extensions>
      <gpxdata:hr>164</gpxdata:hr>
      <gpxdata:cadence>99</gpxdata:cadence> 
    </extensions>
  </trkpt>
```

The GPX file is correct and passes unmarshalling like this:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(GpxType.class, com.cluetrust.xml.gpxdata._1._0.ObjectFactory.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
File file = new File("src/test/resources/gpx-example.gpx");
JAXBElement<GpxType> unmarshal = (JAXBElement<GpxType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
GpxType gpx = unmarshal.getValue();
```

Two things for me are odd. First off all I have to unmarshal to a JAXBElement and cannot go straight to GpxType, I have to go to the JAXBElement first.

Second of all and that is (for me the biggest problem) once I have the GpxType object. Part is indeed done, but the extensions are not:

```
ExtensionsType extensions = gpx.getExtensions();
        List<Object> extensionsAny = extensions.getAny();
        for (Object object : extensionsAny){
            System.out.println(object.getClass());
            if (object instanceof JAXBElement) {
                JAXBElement element = (JAXBElement) object;
                LapType lapType = (LapType) element.getValue();
                System.out.println(lapType.getStartTime());

            }
```

It seems I have to jump through some hoops here. I have setup a very small project on github where this is shown [jaxbproblem](https://github.com/ronsmits/jaxbproblem). The complete example GPX file i am using is there too. The namespaces in it are correct:

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
 xmlns:gpxdata="http://www.cluetrust.com/XML/GPXDATA/1/0"
 creator="pytrainer http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytrainer" version="1.1">
```

EDIT:
Relevant part in the schema is :

```
<xsd:element name="lap" type="lapType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Lap is used to contain information about an individual lap of activity.
            Depending upon the device, this may contain a variety of additional information.
            Depending upon the device, this may be contained within a run or course.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

and:

```
<xsd:complexType name="lapType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="index" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>The index of the lap in the internal list.</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="startPoint" type="locationType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>The starting point of the lap in Lat/Long</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="endPoint" type="locationType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>The ending point of the lap in Lat/Long</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="startTime" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>The starting time of the lap</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="elapsedTime" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>The total elapsed time of the lap in seconds</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="calories" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>The number of calories burned during the lap</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="distance" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>Distance (in m) covered during the lap</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="trackReference" type="trackReferenceType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>Reference information for the track which corresponds to this lap</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="summary" type="summaryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>Performance summary elements summarizing different performance measurements, such as cadence, hr, etc.</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="trigger" type="triggerType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>The trigger of the lap.  On some devices, the lap may be manual or automatic based on attributes known by the device.</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="intensity" type="intensityKind" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xsd:annotation><xsd:documentation>The intensity of the lap (whether resting or active)</xsd:documentation></xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This is just one of the many types that are being introduced with this schema that can be found [here](https://github.com/ronsmits/jaxbproblem/blob/master/src/main/schema/pxdata10.xsd)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you generate your objects from an XML Schema?  If so what does the portion on the XML Schema look like that corresponds to the part of the model you find odd?

Comment: I used [schema file](https://github.com/ronsmits/jaxbproblem/blob/master/src/main/schema/pxdata10.xsd) to generate the objects.  I will add the relevant parts to the original post